# Class Attribute is clearly there, but python cant find it

Tags: python, class, object, attributeerror

Why am i getting this attribute error?

```
class GameState(object):
  """Keeps track game state variables"""
  def __init__(self, convo_flag=0, characters_talked_to=0, convo_log=(None)):
    self.convo_flag = convo_flag
    self.characters_talked_to = characters_talked_to
    self.convo_log = convo_log

def welcome_screen():
  global LAST_NAME
  global BULLY
  global DAY

  raw_input(messages.WELCOME)

  LAST_NAME = raw_input(messages.LAST_NAME)
  BULLY = characters.random_character(cclass='Camper', gender='m')

  print 'Your name is Pickett %s' % LAST_NAME

  messages.print_messages([
    messages.EXPLANATION,
    messages.BUS_LOADING,
    messages.CRACK,
    messages.GAME_KID_LOST])

  return week_one(DAY)

def week_one(day):
  if day == 1:
    messages.print_messages(messages.WEEK_ONE[day])
    campers = characters.random_character_sample(cclass='Camper', count=5)
    people_outside_theater = campers + [characters.TROID]

    while GameState.characters_talked_to != 3:
```

I dont get why im getting this attribute error, i totally declared it in that constructor, is there something i am missing were i need to declare it outside the constructor? This is really racking my brain.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pickett.py", line 44, in welcome_screen
    return week_one(DAY)
  File "pickett.py", line 52, in week_one
    while GameState.characters_talked_to != 3:
AttributeError: type object 'GameState' has no attribute 'characters_talked_to'
```

Comment: If it was "really" there, then Python would find it. Be careful with assertions and practice writing titles/questions in a more neutral tone. (Also "class attributes" and "[object] data attributes" are different..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance in order you use your class like this:

```
gameState = GameState()
while gameState.characters_talked_to != 3:
```

In your code you were trying to access [class-level attribute](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/class_attributes.html) which is not defined in your class.

Comment: I made those changes, but I am still getting the exact same error! That GameState has no attribute called yada yada yada

Comment: That was my mistake on the edit, i made a new one to reflect the current state of my code.

Comment: It works! My bad, forgot i needed to reload the module, still a python noob, thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Your `__init__` function sets `characters_talked_to` on `self`, which is an instance of `GameState`.

You did not set it on `GameState`, which is a class.

Neither did you create any instances of `GameState`, so in any case `__init__` is never called by your program.